# How can i pass array through ajax

Tags: api, jquery

I want to post the following content through Ajax. How can I do this ?

```
<form method="post" action="http://supersaas.com/api/users">
<input type="hidden" id="account" value="robintest">
 <input type="hidden" id="id" value="59fk"> 
<input type="hidden" id="user[name]" name="user[name]" value="robin@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" id="user[full_name]" name="user[full_name]" value="thomas">
<input type="hidden" id="user[phone]" name="user[phone]" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="user[address]" name="user[address]" value="">
<input type ="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I tried the following code

```
 $.ajax({
 type: "post",
 url: "http://http://www.supersaas.com/api/users",
 data: {account:'sixcreeksTest', id:id,user[name]:name,user[address]:address}
 }).done(function( result ) {
 alert(result);
 });
```

but this gives syntax error..

I need to pass the  variables as such because I am passing to an SAAS. So I don't have control over the server.

Comment: your json is not well formated for a javascript parser, [] signes are not allowed in property name for an object, the second solution from Jayantha is right formated.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the json object like this,

```
data: {account:'sixcreeksTest', id:id,checksome:checksome,user:{name:name,address:address}}
```

Or if you need to pass it as a form data instead of json, you can do like this,

```
data: {account:'sixcreeksTest', id:id,'user[name]':name,'user[address]':address}
```

Answer (score 0):

try [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to avoid mistakes

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "post",
   url: "http://http://www.supersaas.com/api/users",
   data: $('form').serialize(), 
   success: function(result) {
     alert(result);
   }
 });
```